# Can't create code that selects 10 out of 25 different strings uniquely C#

Tags: c#, random

I am trying to make a simple math program in C# I have created a button, textbox and set 25 variable to strings (sentences, in this case the questions). I want the program to pick 10 of the questions with no duplicates when i hit the button and display the strings in the textbox.

Main problem is cant get the program to pick 10 unique strings, appreciate your help

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Math_generator
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Generate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            HashSet<int> numbers = new HashSet<int>();
            while (numbers.Count < 6)
            {
                numbers.Add(random.Next(1, 49));
            }
            TestResults.Text = "Hey " + numbers.ToString();
        } 

        }




        //Random random = new Random();
        //int MultipleChoice = random.Next(1, 26);


        //int MultipleChoice2 = random.Next(1, 26);

        //if (MultipleChoice2 == MultipleChoice)
        //{

        //    MultipleChoice2 = random.Next(1, 26);
        //}


        //    int MultipleChoice3 = random.Next(1, 26);
        //    if (MultipleChoice3 == MultipleChoice || MultipleChoice3 == MultipleChoice2)
        //    {

        //        MultipleChoice3 = random.Next(1, 26);
        //    }


        //    int MultipleChoice4 = random.Next(1, 26);
        //    if (MultipleChoice4 == MultipleChoice || MultipleChoice4 == MultipleChoice2 || MultipleChoice4 == MultipleChoice3)
        //    {

        //    MultipleChoice4 = random.Next(1, 26);
        //     }


        //    int MultipleChoice5 = random.Next(1, 26);
        //    if (MultipleChoice5 == MultipleChoice || MultipleChoice5 == MultipleChoice2 || MultipleChoice5 == MultipleChoice3 || MultipleChoice5 == MultipleChoice4)
        //    {

        //        MultipleChoice5 = random.Next(1, 26);
        //    }

        //    int MultipleChoice6 = random.Next(1, 26);
        //    if (MultipleChoice6 == MultipleChoice || MultipleChoice6 == MultipleChoice2 || MultipleChoice6 == MultipleChoice3 || MultipleChoice6 == MultipleChoice4 || MultipleChoice6 == MultipleChoice5)
        //    {

        //        MultipleChoice6 = random.Next(1, 26);
        //    }

        //    int MultipleChoice7 = random.Next(1, 26);
        //    if (MultipleChoice7 == MultipleChoice || MultipleChoice7 == MultipleChoice2 || MultipleChoice7 == MultipleChoice3 || MultipleChoice7 == MultipleChoice4 || MultipleChoice7 == MultipleChoice5 || MultipleChoice7 == MultipleChoice6)
        //    {

        //        MultipleChoice7 = random.Next(1, 26);
        //    }

        //    int MultipleChoice8 = random.Next(1, 26);
        //    if (MultipleChoice8 == MultipleChoice || MultipleChoice8 == MultipleChoice2 || MultipleChoice8 == MultipleChoice3 || MultipleChoice8 == MultipleChoice4 || MultipleChoice8 == MultipleChoice5 || MultipleChoice8 == MultipleChoice6 || MultipleChoice8 == MultipleChoice7)
        //    {

        //        MultipleChoice8 = random.Next(1, 26);
        //    }

        //    int MultipleChoice9 = random.Next(1, 26);
        //    if (MultipleChoice9 == MultipleChoice || MultipleChoice9 == MultipleChoice2 || MultipleChoice9 == MultipleChoice3 || MultipleChoice9 == MultipleChoice4 || MultipleChoice9 == MultipleChoice5 || MultipleChoice9 == MultipleChoice6 || MultipleChoice9 == MultipleChoice7 || MultipleChoice9 == MultipleChoice8)
        //    {

        //        MultipleChoice9 = random.Next(1, 26);
        //    }

        //    int MultipleChoice10 = random.Next(1, 26);
        //if (MultipleChoice10 == MultipleChoice || MultipleChoice10 == MultipleChoice2 || MultipleChoice10 == MultipleChoice3 || MultipleChoice10 == MultipleChoice4 || MultipleChoice10 == MultipleChoice5 || MultipleChoice10 == MultipleChoice6 || MultipleChoice10 == MultipleChoice7 || MultipleChoice10 == MultipleChoice8 || MultipleChoice10 == MultipleChoice9)
        //    {

        //        MultipleChoice10 = random.Next(1, 26);
        //    }
        //TestResults.Text = "your numbers are: " + MultipleChoice + ", " + MultipleChoice2 + ", " + MultipleChoice3 + ", " + MultipleChoice4 + ", " + MultipleChoice5 + ", " + MultipleChoice6 + ", " + MultipleChoice7 + ", " + MultipleChoice8 + ", " + MultipleChoice9 + ", " + MultipleChoice10;



    }
```

Comment: Can you show your code please?

Comment: Add them into a `List<string>` and use `list.Distinct.Take(10)`. How you want to show them in the `TextBox`? Maybe so: `txt.Text = String.Join(Environemnt.NewLine, list.Distinct.Take(10))`.

Comment: new to coding and couldn't find anything specific to do with my problem

Comment: @deathblade80 - Please don't edit your question so as to make the existing answers look ridiculous. The question and the answers are here to support the community so you should strive to keep them as clear and as relevant as possible.

Answer (score 5):

What you want to do is *shuffle* your set of 25 strings and then take the first ten. You can do that like this:

```
var shuffled = myStrings.OrderBy(x => random.Next()).Take(10).ToList();
```

Forestalling the frequent bad answers:

Some people will tell you to order by a new guid to shuffle; do not do this. Guids guarantee uniqueness, not randomness.

And some people will tell you that writing ten lines of code to make a Fischer-Yates shuffle is superior to writing one line of code, because Fischer-Yates is more efficient as the size of the list grows to millions or billions; this is expending effort to solve a problem you don't have today and will not ever have tomorrow.

Comment: You there cause you sound like great help and a great guy for helping people with code, where would i put your code

Comment: @deathblade80: In your program. Start by putting the questions in a list, so that you can manipulate them as a list.

Comment: added them to a list but myStrings is red underline and .next on random.next

Comment: @deathblade80: This might be too hard a problem for you at your current level of knowledge. Try solving an easier problem.

Answer (score -1):

you have 25 questions.
For 10 of them, you need a random between 1 and 25 and a list of 10 elements,
and for each random, search for unique restriction. If you have the unique restriction, add it to list.

You have advanced code for optimize this, but is not essential.

In your code, you are searching for 6 elements and select one between 50 options. Change the sizes, and add validation.